# mysql show innodb status output

Tags: mysql, database, buffer, innodb, status

i am trying to view the buffer pool and row stats that is usually shown when running `SHOW INNODB STATUS`.

But for some reason this infomation is not being displayed, just lots of record locks.
Does anyone now how to view the buffer pool infomation?

**Update**

After reading the MySQL docs again, i noticed this:

```
InnoDB Monitor output is limited to 64,000 bytes when produced using 
the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS statement. This limit does not apply to 
output written to the server's error output.
```

**Answer**
I found the answer i was looking for,

here: [A quest for the full InnoDB status](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/10/31/full-innodb-status/)

Also how to clear the deadlocks here: [How to deliberately cause a deadlock in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql/)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the mysql docs again, i noticed this: "InnoDB Monitor output is limited to 64,000 bytes when produced using the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS statement. This limit does not apply to output written to the server's error output."

here is more information about inndb status: A quest for the full InnoDB status

Also how to clear the deadlocks here: How to deliberately cause a deadlock in MySQL

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

See here for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html

Comment: that gives the same output as SHOW INNODB STATUS

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` include all o/p you look for. You need to use `\G` instead semicolon `;` which will give you readable output. Refer the link I have provided.

Comment: Like i said SHOW INNODB STATUS gives the exact same output as SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS. SHOW INNODB STATUS is the old statement but still works. The problem is the output is limited to 64,000 bytes.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for that `\G` tip. I never knew about that.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have the InnoDB Buffer Pool in its INFORMATION_SCHEMA database

Interesting, XtraDB (used in MariaDB and Percona Server) does have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES.

If you really need to see the InnoDB Buffer Pool, switch to MariaDB or Percona Server.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool%';
```

Comment: All the infomation is there what i needed, just not as neatly or an average like SHOW INNODB STATUS. Thanks